# Creating an Unwrapped Widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a widget similar to the text widget but I don't want it to be wrapped and I don't want any divs or formatting added around it. This will be used for javascript right before the closing  tag so I'm just trying to have the plain/basic info thats typed into the widget.  What else do I need besides what I have below? Did I do this right?

```
function 123_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Scripts', '123' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', '123_widgets_init' );
```

Comment: Why don't you use `wp_enque_script` to add your script to the page?

Comment: they aren't predefined scripts

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean they aren´t predefined ?

Comment: @obmerk-ninenine javascript using <script> ... </script> will be entered directly into the widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , you did right . any text widget can take javascript - if you want to get rid of the divs and p tags and classes - your code should be enough.

you can also use some filters to clean other things .

Actually, I had a code for such a widget -  I do not remember from which website I took it (some snippet repository) but it is basically the text widget duplicated with some small changes.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Text widget for Javascript
Plugin URI: Unknown 
Description: Adds a Text widget with Javascript support - basically empty all divs classes etc.
Version: 3.1
Author: Unknown (code source unknown. compiled by Obmerk99)
Author URI: Unknown
License: GPL2
Network: true
*/

/**********************************************
 * Text widget class with small twicks for JS *
 **********************************************/

class WP_Widget_Text_For_JS extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'widget_text', 'description' => __('Javascript Text Widget'));
        $control_ops = array('width' => 400, 'height' => 350);
        parent::__construct('text', __('Text'), $widget_ops, $control_ops);
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base);
        $text = apply_filters( 'widget_text', $instance['text'], $instance );
        $before_widget = ''; $after_widget =''; $before_title=''; $after_title='';$after_widget=''; //empty all
        echo $before_widget;
        if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; } ?>
            <div class="textwidget"><?php echo $instance['filter'] ? wpautop($text) : $text; ?></div>
        <?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['text'] =  $new_instance['text'];
        $instance['filter'] = isset($new_instance['filter']);
        return $instance;
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '', 'text' => '' ) );
        $title = strip_tags($instance['title']);
        $text = esc_textarea($instance['text']);
?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" /></p>

        <textarea class="widefat" rows="16" cols="20" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text'); ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>

        <p><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('filter'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('filter'); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked(isset($instance['filter']) ? $instance['filter'] : 0); ?> />&nbsp;<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('filter'); ?>"><?php _e('Automatically add paragraphs'); ?></label></p>
<?php
    }
}
function wp_o99_javascript_text_widget(){
    // unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Text'); // Only if you really want to .
    register_widget('WP_Widget_Text_For_JS');
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'wp_o99_javascript_text_widget', 1);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use my plugin [Magic Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-widgets/). It has a text widget which doesn’t use the sidebar parameters, and it creates special widget areas in the header and footer of the front-end and back-end views.

You can take the [plain widget from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/1594985).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of steps left to get to where you want

1. Create a new sidebar-xxx.php file that calls your sidebar you created
2. Create a [widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) to drop into that sidebar.
3. Call `get_sidebar('xxx');` where you want it to display the widgets in your sidebar.

When creating the sidebar file or the widget you can exclude adding formatting or wrappers and just echo the input from the widget

http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API